# Query to Group by and Count

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I need help with an Oracle query to group by column 1 and return the count of number characters that match in the column_2, the matching needs to start from Right-Hand-Side i.e last character of column 2 , because some chars at the start of column are always different.

```
COLUMN_1                            COLUMN_2
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    d1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19
```

The output of running the query on above should be

```
COLUMN_1                            Count_of_COLUMN_2
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    24
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    24
```

I will  be using this identify if there is a pattern in column 2, i.e I always have same number of matching characters.

Comment: You have to define where on your string starts the `Right-Hand-Side` is it a number of chars? is it a pattern? is it a number from left to right or from right to left ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Starting from last character in column 2 value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're after any matching characters - starting from the right hand side of the string - even if they're non-adjacent (eg. 'abc' and 'badc' has a matching count of 2, since positions 1 and 3 (from the right hand side) match in both columns), then this should do the trick:

```
with sample_data as (select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, 'd1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual)
select     column_1,
           column_2,
           count(case when substr(column_1, -level, 1) = substr(column_2, -level, 1) then 1 end) cnt_matching_chars
from       sample_data
connect by prior column_1 = column_1
           and prior column_2 = column_2
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
           and level <= length(column_2)
group by   column_1,
           column_2;

COLUMN_1                         COLUMN_2                         CNT_MATCHING_CHARS
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- ------------------
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 25
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19                 24
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 25
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19                 24
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 d1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19                 26
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 26
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19                 23
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 23
```

This basically takes the strings, pivots them into rows for each character in the string in column2, and then compares the characters in the same position (counting from the right hand edge), and then counts them.

---

If, however, you're looking for the set of concurrent matching characters from the right hand side, and don't care about any subsequent characters that match further on the left after the "break", then the following should do the trick:

```
with sample_data as (select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, 'd1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual)
select   column_1,
         column_2,
         count(matching_chars) cnt_matching_chars
from     (select     column_1,
                     column_2,
                     case when substr(column_1, -level, 1) = substr(column_2, -level, 1) then 1 end matching_chars,
                     row_number() over (partition by column_1, column_2
                                        order by level)
                       - row_number() over (partition by column_1, column_2, case when substr(column_1, -level, 1) = substr(column_2, -level, 1) then 1 end
                                            order by level) grp
          from       sample_data
          connect by prior column_1 = column_1
                     and prior column_2 = column_2
                     and prior sys_guid() is not null
                     and level <= length(column_2))
where    grp = 0
group by column_1,
         column_2,
         grp
order by column_1,
         column_2;

COLUMN_1                         COLUMN_2                         CNT_MATCHING_CHARS
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- ------------------
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 20
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 24
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 24
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8 f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                 25
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19                 20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19                 20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19                 20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19 d1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19                 25
```

This does a similar thing to work out the matching characters, but it also uses [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) to work out the groups of matching characters, before taking the first group and performing the count.

---

If you're after the min count for all column_2 rows per column_1, then you need to throw another group by around the query, eg, for the second query that would be:

```
with sample_data as (select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '5ce63254860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, 'd1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual)
select   column_1,
         min(cnt_matching_chars) min_cnt_matching_chars
from     (select   column_1,
                   column_2,
                   count(matching_chars) cnt_matching_chars
          from     (select     column_1,
                               column_2,
                               case when substr(column_1, -level, 1) = substr(column_2, -level, 1) then 1 end matching_chars,
                               row_number() over (partition by column_1, column_2
                                                  order by level)
                                 - row_number() over (partition by column_1, column_2, case when substr(column_1, -level, 1) = substr(column_2, -level, 1) then 1 end
                                                      order by level) grp
                    from       sample_data
                    connect by prior column_1 = column_1
                               and prior column_2 = column_2
                               and prior sys_guid() is not null
                               and level <= length(column_2))
          where    grp = 0
          group by column_1,
                   column_2,
                   grp)
group by column_1
order by column_1;

COLUMN_1                         MIN_CNT_MATCHING_CHARS
-------------------------------- ----------------------
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8                     20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19                     20
```

Comment: Very nice!  What's the runtime like?  I was going to suggest to OP that it might be easier to dump the data out of the DB and use bit operations in their language of choice, since I can't expect this type of query to run with any speed on a DB.

Comment: Both queries run in < 200ms for me with the test set of data. I would imagine it would take a lot longer for any decent amount of data, though! It's up to the OP to test against their dataset and work out if it's feasible to use or not.

Comment: @Boneist I have around 200,000 records to test, the columns 1 and 2 in the query both have a length of 255 chars, but i tested few samples and max 32 chars are used

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with simple regex. No need to split strings to individual characters.

```
with sample_data as (select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '5ce6354860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c89' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, 'f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select '53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_1, '0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, 'd1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual union all
                     select 'c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19' column_1, '0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19' column_2 from dual)
select column_1,column_2,
length(regexp_substr(column_1 ||'-'|| column_2,'(\w+)-.*\1$',1,1,'i',1))
from sample_data;

column_1                            column_2                            matching_chars
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    5ce6354860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c89    null
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    f35c3a08860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    24
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    f49712bc860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    25
53bf8a7c860a11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    0df52992860b11e5a7ab2b0669b590c8    20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    d1fd4548860811e5983f09a623895e19    25
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    87ea0648860911e5983f09a623895e19    20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    0316e024860b11e5983f09a623895e19    20
c05d6368860811e5983f09a623895e19    0450d68e860b11e5983f09a623895e19    20
```

Idea is to join the strings using a delimiter and use backreference to extract the matching characters before the delimiter and at the end of the string.
Then find the length of the extracted string.